# Different transition on remove class

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Below is the code what I have tried. What I need is when the class get removed after 5s. The notification box should not move up. Just get fade out at same place.

This can be done by adding one more class in setTimeout. I am looking to avoid that.

```js
$('.notify').click(function() {
  $('.note').addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.note').removeClass('show');
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.note {
  top: 0%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -150px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1s, opacity 1.5s;
}

.show {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="notify">click here</button>
<div class="note">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delay in **transition: top 1s 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;** and add **transition: top 1s,opacity 1.5s;** in **.show** class

```js
$('.notify').click(function() {
  $('.note').addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.note').removeClass('show');
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.note {
  top: 0%;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -150px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1s 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
}

.show {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 1s,opacity 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="notify">click here</button>
<div class="note">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks @Tushar

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it *pure CSS* with the `:target` *selector* and simple `animation`:

```css
#note {
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -150px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#note:target {
  top: 50%;
  animation: fadeOut 6s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  16.67%, 83.33% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<a href="#note"><button class="notify">click here</button></a>
<div id="note">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>
```

But the only limitation is that it can only run once.

Comment: This is good idea. But I have a close button with this notification box and also few conditions to handle for which JS is needed. I'll try to implement this idea. Thanks for you help.